# What did Captain America mean after being kissed by Black Widow?

Tags: dialogue, plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, captain-america-the-winter-soldier

In *Captain America: The Winter Soldier*, when Black Widow kissed Captain America in the shopping mall to avoid getting caught, Black Widow asked him if he still feels uncomfortable while Captain said:

> It's not exactly the word I would use.

What did he mean? Did he mean he has some old-fashioned way to say that he was uncomfortable?

Comment: I haven't seen the movie recently, but he may have meant that he was aroused.

Comment: I haven't seen the movie too. What happens next ?

Comment: I'm not trying to spoil the fun to watch this movie . So if you want to know what happen next , just watch it . it's a good movie and you won't regret watching it :D

Answer (score 41, accepted):

I want to say it was his polite way of saying, **"Not really, it made me aroused."**

When men become aroused, well, you likely know what happens, and it can lead to some slight...discomfort? Cap is definitely still fairly old fashioned as you put it, and simply wanted to be polite and not vulgar.

Comment: He certainly doesn't like bad language.

Comment: He's smooth as hell, though.

Comment: @MattD: Language!

Comment: @MasonWheeler I was initially wondering why someone would care to call me out for using the word hell, then it hit me. Well played, sir, well played.

Comment: It's worth adding that Cap might well be a virgin, or have been one at the time.   At least, Chris Evans implies as much.    https://moviepilot.com/posts/2896124