# What does Steve Rogers mean in this dialogue?

Tags: dialogue, marvel-cinematic-universe, avengers-age-of-ultron

In the movie [Avengers: Age of Ultron](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt2395427/) Steve Rogers said to Bruce Banner

> I have seen her flirt, upclose

It was about Black Widow. What does that mean? Is that some dialogue theatrics or is there any reference there?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Yes, In *Captain America: Winter Soldier*, there's a scene where Natasha kisses cap to avoid getting caught by bad guys. Also check this [question](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/33644/what-did-captain-america-mean-after-being-kissed-by-black-widow) and I believe he was referring to that situation.

Here's the scene.

Comment: There's also quite a bit of banter before and after that between them, that she engages in mostly to make straight-arrow nice guy Steve Rogers uncomfortable, as personal entertainment.